# MVCSiteMap Port Problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, sitemap, mvcsitemapprovider

I am using MVCSiteMap - http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/ -  with Azure and I am trying to figure out how I can get it to remove the PORT number at the end of the generated sitemap.

Currently, I am getting

```
http://127.0.0.1:5100/
```

For this url and all others. Does anyone have any experience with this or know how to remove the port no ?

Answer (score 0):

If you run your code on production (something.cloudapp.net), this port number should dissappear.